# KDE's dolphin for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, ftp, file-management

I like using KDE's Dolphin on Linux. Two important things that it can do are:

- Open FTP and other locations like regular folders, including opening files for editing
- Split the explorer window into two panes side by side

Does anyone know a good, free program for Windows that can do the same?

Comment: why is this question close? there is a solution for that and dont find anywhere to put that: https://binary-factory.kde.org/job/Dolphin_Release_win64/

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud As the older and wiser iteration of OP, I would agree that this question doesn't belong on this site. Nice to know that one could run Dolphin on Windows though, even if I personally hardly have a need for it any longer. Coincidentally, I've recently returned to KDE and Dolphin after having been on GNOME for many years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), the Jesus Tool of File Managers.

Comment: Care to explain why this suits the OP's needs?

Comment: No, but it's Jesus Tool of File Managers, lol.

Comment: Just my 2 cents there... Check double commander, it's Open Source (like Dolphin), GPL v2, and frequently updated. So far the best option I did find. Too bad that Dolphin is not available for Windows BTW. It's for a decade that Windows lags far behind free KDE/Plasma as desktop manager, and I don't feel it will change. If at least they could allow <CTRL>+T to open a new tab...

Answer (score 11):

The [KDE on Windows](http://windows.kde.org/) project will let you use Dolphin on Windows.

Comment: sorry for noob comment but when I come to your link, there is no "Download" menu nor Dolphin-windows-build-version :(

Comment: @Luke maybe 10 years later it is no longer available?

Comment: Sad to know that. After some more searched, i've found that instead of maintain a fork of dolphin built for windows, they packed all of it to a single package kde-for-windows.

Answer (score 2):

I use [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). It does exactly what you need it to.

Comment: Good client. Avoid the server, as it makes unwanted connections to unknown servers.

Comment: Not entirely. In filezilla you can't open two ftp locations next to eachother. Editing files is a hassle (right click -> edit -> make changes -> save -> confirm upload) compared to Dolphin. It's a good client, but just for uploading and downloading.

Comment: @kmarsh my attention was drawn to this question again, years later now, and your comment gave me a bit of a WTF moment. But looking into it some more, I found stories of people running it without a firewall, resulting in random "hackers" attempting to connect to it, which would also make the server connect to them due to the quirks of Active FTP. That's not really an issue with the software itself though. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom It's been a while so my memory may be a bit faulty, but here goes. The IT dept (not including me) where I worked at the time noted multiple connections to Chinese IP addresses. All hosts were behind some kind of firewall, for whatever that is worth. The software quickly made our explicitly dis-approved list. Other alternatives were available. I was never familiar with the firewall config, and the hosts may have been compromised in other ways, it may have been premature to blame FileZilla. However a history of CVE's from 2005 to 2007 sealed the deal.

Answer (score 2):

No, they won't.  I've been looking around for something like Konqueror, or Dolphin for windows and it doesn't exist.  The ease of dealing with files, local or remote.  Doing file type conversions, or in window text editing.  Unpacking or packing zip, tar, rar, or bzip.  Moving seamlessly from preview to icon, to text file information.  KIO slaves that let you treat remote filesystems (ssh, ftp, smb) as local.  No there is nothing for windows like it.  Sad, but true.

Comment: Windows has network filesystem support *built-in,* coming with SMB and WebDAV support out of the box, NFS optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/) for SFTP support directy in Windows Explorer and [Windows Double Explorer](http://wde.codeplex.com/) for browsing with two or more panels.

These solutions are native for Windows and work nice.

Answer (score 1):

[xplorer²](http://zabkat.com/) and [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) are able to do what you want. However, both will cost you money.

[FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) is a free file manager replacement with FTP and split screen support. KDE on Windows may also work.

Answer (score 1):

**[SpeedCommander](http://www.speedproject.de/enu/index.html)**

> SpeedCommander is a comfortable file manager. It builds on the proven two window technology and offers a multitude of exclusive features. Sort, copy, move or delete your files either using the keyboard or the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's Dolphin for Windows. It the file manager I use on my Windows 7. I must admit it doesn't work as well on Windows as it does in Linux.

Comment: How could you use it? 
I went to https://community.kde.org/Windows and nothing there for me to `download` or `install`

Comment: https://binary-factory.kde.org/job/Dolphin_Release_win64/

Answer (score 0):

I use Dolphin on KDE and NexusFile on Windows.  It is a different experience but not too bad, and also reminds me of StupenDOS with the color scheme (not to show my age there).